# Is there a way to highlight required input fields in Vue Formulation?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-formulate

So I am trying to create a form using Vue Formulation. I have a few input fields that are required. Is it even possible to highlight them somehow? I have read Vue Formulation doc, but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply give the required fields a different styling/CSS class.

If you are really fancy, you could try to read the attributes of the DOM elements (with [attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()) or [refs](https://blog.logrocket.com/vue-refs-accessing-dom-elements/)), but haven't tried that and it is probably not worthwhile.